# Is the additive group of real numbers (R,+) compact?

Tags: lie-groups, compact-manifolds

I have a very naive question about basic topology. My goal is to determine the conditions on a vector field in order for its flow to define a proper (R,+)-action. I understand that if the group G is compact, then the G-action is proper so I have to determine if (R,+) is compact. It seems to me that being homomorph to the (compact) circle group via the exponential function which is continuous, then (R,+) must be compact as well but I didn't find any explicit proof of this assertion. Can someone help me with that ? Thanks very much

More precisely, I want to use the following property: 
Let X and Y be two topological spaces, if $f:X\mapsto Y$ is continuous and X is compact, then $f(X)$ is compact. 
The circle Lie group $T=\{z\in \mathbb C|\,  |z|=1\}$ is compact and there is an homomorphism (the exponential function) $exp:T\mapsto (R,+)$ which is continuous. Therefore, identifying X=T and Y=(R,+), (R,+) must be compact ?

Ok, now I see my (rookie) mistake. Thanks to everyone !

Comment: $\Bbb R$ is not homeomorphic to $S^1$, if that is what you're saying.

Comment: There is a Lie group homomorphism from $\Bbb{R}$ onto $S^1$, which might be what you're talking about, but that's irrelevant to compactness of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: The exponential function does not go from $T$ to $R$. It goes from $R$ to $T$.

Comment: @ChrisEagle: is the Lie group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ *onto* $S^1$?

Answer (score 8):

No, $\Bbb{R}$ is not compact (with the standard topology). The cover by open intervals $(-n,n)$ has no finite subcover.

Comment: Thanks fo your quick answer. Are you talking about R as the set of real numbers or about the Lie group (R,+) ? If you confirm that (R,+) is noncompact, do you see the flaw in the previously sketched argument ?
Thanks again

Comment: I'm talking about the real numbers with their standard topology. If you're putting some other topology on them, then my answer doesn't apply. As to your argument, it's incomprehensible gibberish.

Comment: I think the edited version of the question converts the argument from incomprehensible gibberish to an egregious error in logic, namely reversing an implication without any justification. After citing the theorem that, for continuous $f$, compactness of $X$ implies compacness of $f(X)$, and knowing that, in the situation at hand ($f=\exp$ and $X=\mathbb R$), $f(X)$ is compact, the OP wants to infer that $X$ is compact.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Was "incomprehensible gibberish." necessary? I guess incomprehensible would have sufficed...

Comment: @PeterTamaroff: I'm not sure what "necessary" could possibly mean in this context.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I mean it was uncalled for.

Answer (score 3):

As Chris Eagle pointed out, the group $G = (\mathbb{R},+)$ isn't compact. Your argument regarding the function $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ defined by $\varphi(x) = e^{ix}$ (or $\varphi(x) = (\cos x,\sin x)$) doesn't show that $G$ is compact, since the function $\varphi$ isn't a bijection (and hence isn't a homeomorphism).

Note, in your edit, the spaces $X$ and $Y$ are backwards; $\exp: \mathbb{R} \to S^1$ not the other way around. Also when you just say "the exponential function", it leads me (and most others, I assume) to think of either the map $x \mapsto e^x$ or the exponential map from a Lie algebra to its Lie group. So unless you're referring to one of those maps (which you're not in this case, since the former is a map $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{>0}$ and the latter is $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$), you should probably be more specific.

On the other hand, the function $\varphi$ is locally injective and therefore a local homeomorphism. So if you wanted to, you could use it to argue that $G$ is *locally compact* (every point has a compact neighborhood), although there are easier ways to see this.